# ifstream --> ofstream c++

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream

I have a function that gets ifstream variable, but I have to write into this file in some situations. E.g.

```
main()
{
  ifstream dataFile("filename.txt");
  foo(dataFile);
}

void foo(ifstream &df)
{
  if(df.good()) {...}
  else {
     //here I need to write str into the "filename.txt"
     //but I don't know how to do it properly!
  }
}
```

As I can imagine, the simplest way is to get somehow name of the file from df in foo()... But how?

imagine:
I CAN'T use fstream.
For some reason **I have only ifstream&** and **don't know** name of the file.
E.g. I get ifstream& from some closed library function.

Comment: Do not pass a stream by value pass it by reference. `void foo(ifstream& df)`

Comment: Can you pass the filename as a parameter to foo? If you can, simply instantiate a std::ostream(filename) within foo and work with that. Otherwise, you can replace ifstream with fstream (which supports both) input and output.

Comment: Can't you change the function so that it takes an `fstream` instead of an `ifstream`? An `ifstream` is specifically for *reading* from a file, not for writing.

Comment: How about you open it as read-write with `fstream`, which allows reading and writing, instead of `ifstream` or `ofstream`?

Answer (score 4):

Use fstream rather than ifstream:

```
fstream dataFile("filename.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
```

With this you can read and write to the file.

And OF COURSE, pass your fstream object by reference, not by value. fstream is non-copyable.

Comment: Not that it's appropriate here, nor relevant to the answer, but with C++11, streams are movable.

Comment: @PeteBecker interesting to know, thanks. Although I don't see a reason why one should pass a filestream by value... I think the guy in the question is passing by value just due of lack of experience.

Comment: but the question is to "get the goal" when I CAN'T use fstream.
at some reason I HAVE ONLY ifstream& and NEED to write into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately given your restrictions that you have only an `ifstream` and no filename, there is no portable way to write back into that file.

There *may* be non-portable ways to solve this problem. For example some unix implementations may provide an `fd` function on the `filebuf` object you can obtain from `rdbuf` in the `ifstream`. Windows may or may not provide a similar capability.

I'll close by noting that it sounds like you may be solving the wrong problem here, and you should at least take a moment to visit your design (and why you need to write to a file whose name you do not know).